# How to set selected background color of UITableViewCell when not in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I don't see why this would matter, but I'm having some trouble getting it to work.

Disclaimer: This is my first iOS app (or ANY Apple development for that matter, and the app needs to be done yesterday, so excuse any rushed-looking code please).

I'm using the SWRevealViewController library to create a Facebook-esque "side view" when a button on the home view navigation controller is clicked. It works great, love it. This view holds a UITableView with only two static cells, and I just received a request to add a cell to the very bottom of the view.

It didn't seem obvious to try to get that third cell "in" the UITableView, so in my xib I just created a UITableViewCell outside of the UITableView, and put it at the bottom of the view. It then hooked it up to my controller using the standard IBOutlet workflow.

Back in my viewDidLoad I skinned the rogue cell to look like the rest of the tablecells, added some wording, added a handler to make it open up my company's website when clicked, and all of that works fine. I did all of this stuff for the "regular" table cells in my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

BUT for some reason when I click on the cell, it's not being highlighted like my other regular cells when I click on it! Why!

CODE:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    } else {
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UILabel *lblView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 3.0, 187.0, cell.frame.size.height)];
    [lblView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FuturaStd-Bold" size:12]];
    lblView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.f) green:(241/255.f) blue:(204/255.f) alpha:1.0];
    lblView.tag = 1;
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        [lblView setText:@"SCHEDULE"];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        [lblView setText:@"SPEAKERS"];
    }
    lblView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblView];

    UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 277, 58)];
    av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    av.opaque = NO;
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blackBar.png"];
    cell.backgroundView = av;

    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(240/255.f) green:(145/255.f) blue:(62/255.f) alpha:1.0]];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

    return cell;
}
```

The above code works fine for my "regular cells". That last bit before I return the cell is what sets the background highlight a weird orange color when it's "being clicked".

The code below is the SAME THING but in my viewDidLoad, and it's not setting the background highlight color when being clicked.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //... stuff

    UILabel *lblView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 3.0, 187.0, _roguecell.frame.size.height)];
    [lblView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FuturaStd-Bold" size:12]];
    lblView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.f) green:(241/255.f) blue:(204/255.f) alpha:1.0];
    [lblView setText:@"IT'S A SECRET LOL"];
    lblView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [_roguecell.contentView addSubview:lblView];

    UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 277, 58)];
    av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    av.opaque = NO;
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blackBar.png"];
    _roguecell.backgroundView = av;

    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(240/255.f) green:(145/255.f) blue:(62/255.f) alpha:1.0]];
    [_roguecell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [_roguecell addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}
```

Maybe it has something to do with my xib file I have the UITableView extending down the entire view, and the rogue UITableViewCell "on top" of it (but not in it obviously). I tried messing around with the locations of the table and the cell, but that didn't do anything.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: So you are adding the rogue cell to table view header?

Comment: @verbumdei Nope, my xib view hierarchy looks like this:
-UIView
--UIToolbar
--UILabel
--UITableView
--UITableViewCell

Comment: If your table uses static cells, you shouldn't even be implementing the table view data source methods. You should have IBOutlets to the cell or the UI elements themselves, and populate them in viewDiLoad like you would any other label or image view.

Comment: @rdelmar This is good to know. It makes sense. During my next re-write (I've re-written this thing from scratch like 5 times as I figure out better ways to do it) I'll hook up those static cells directly with the IBOutlets.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing my rogue UITableViewCell, and upping the total number of cells in my UITableView from 2 to 4. The 3rd cell I removed my custom background from, didn't add any text to, disabled user interaction from, and set the height using the `- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method to fill up the rest of the table leaving only enough room at the bottom for my "footer" cell.